# Is it possible to detect how user accessed the app in react native?

Tags: xcode, react-native

I am creating a voice call app and I am trying to detect how the user accessed the menu. If they accessed through top orange voice btn or just clicking on the app.

[image]

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: More detail is supposed